# Android app crash in Nougat

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-7.0-nougat

am new to android dev. created an app in Android Studio 2.2 and the android version 6.0. Right now just updated to android studio 2.3. It's not working in my mobile.

**Build.Gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "payment.online.rely.latitude"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
       testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'



    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
    import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */

    private static final int LONG_DELAY = 3500;

    String lat = "", lon = "";
    GPSTracker gps;
    TextView location,citi,statee,pin,cou;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        location = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);
        citi = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.loc);
        statee = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sta);
        pin = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pin);
        cou = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cou);


        Button btnLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);
        btnLocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT)
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled
                if(gps.canGetLocation()) {

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    Geocoder geocoder;
                    List<Address> addresses;
                    geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    String address = null, subcity = null, city=null,state = null,country = null,postalCode = null;
                    try {
                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

                        address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                        subcity = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                        //city = addresses.get(0).getSubAdminArea();
                        state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                        country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                        postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                        String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    location.setText(address);
                    citi.setText(subcity);
                    statee.setText(state);
                    pin.setText(postalCode);
                    cou.setText(country);
                    // \n is for new line
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + gps.getLatitude() + "\nLong: " + gps.getLongitude() + "\nLocation: " + address + "," + " " + subcity +","+""  +
                           // " " + state + "," + " " + postalCode + "," + " " + country, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else{
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }
        });
    }

}
enter code here[enter image description here][1]
```

**GPSTracker.Java**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by mipstech i5 2 on 20-Apr-17.
 */
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // TODO: Consider calling
                            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                            //                                          int[] grantResults)
                            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                            return location;
                        }
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();



                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();




                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082062/code-will-only-return-0-0-0-0-gps-coordinate-while-throwing-nullpointerexceptio

Comment: What is the actual error message? If you are debugging the app you should be able to see the exception (error details) in the Android Monitor window.

Comment: Nope. can't able to opp the application. The app is crash

Comment: No logcat? I dont think so. There should be something printed with Error tag

Comment: upload your logs

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba                                                                                      FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: payment.online.rely.latitude, PID: 8744
                                                                            java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Answer (score 1):

A quick suggestion would be: You are using build tools version 25 and your dependencies and compiler sdk are using version 24. Can you check if that solves?

**Edit**
You are trying to access your list of positions in invalid index, you should verify if it is a valid index before trying to use it.

Comment: Just change like this:

Comment: oh, you should check index positions before using them

Comment: Could any one tell me, but it's worked on my Android version is 6.0.Now I just update my mobile version to 7.0. It's crashed

Comment: @rajeshKumar You should be able to test that by creating an emulator of Android 6. You can do that from Android Studio: Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba Yeah able to run on the emulator of Android 6 API Level 23. But can't run in Android 7. API Level 25.

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba In the Message in Android Studio it shows :Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

Comment: Is that dependency needed at all? I don't see a reference to it in your imports. Am I missing something? Anyways, please post the call stack of he exception you get when your app crashes on 7. (See the Android Monitor window.)

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba In emulator when i press the button, it crash. In my android mobile 7, is not open. When i click the application the error through.

Comment: @JaroslavZáruba this is the error shows in android monitor.Process: payment.online.rely.latitude, PID: 9464
                                                                            java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: Usually there is chain of method calls that resulted in the error. Seeing that chain would be helpful. Also when your application crashes on start you can still create an error log from within Developer Options in Android settings of your (physical) device.

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

You should change the classpath version.