# GPS Locations Android

Tags: android, gps

I have created a project sunshine which gives weathery detail by tracking your
current location it works fine but sometimes my GPSTracker class which returns me the latitude,longitude and postal code along with the country doesnt return the data at the time and then my app shows then the network error

I dont know whats the problem sometimes it works very fine but sometimes it doesnt.

My GPSTracker class:-

```
package com.example.na462.sunshine;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;


public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
private final Context mContext;

//flag for GPS Status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

//flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location;
public double latitude;
public double longitude;

//The minimum distance to change updates in metters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; //10 metters

//The minimum time beetwen updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

//Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        GPSEnabled.GPS = isGPSEnabled;

        //getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            int afl = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION );

            int acl = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION );

    if (locationManager != null) {

        Log.d("locationManager",""+locationManager);

                if (afl != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && acl != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    public void requestPermissions(@NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode)
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return location;
                }
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                updateGPSCoordinates();
            }

            //if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");

                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        updateGPSCoordinates();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Error : Location", "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
    }

    return location;
}

public void updateGPSCoordinates() {
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 */

public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if (locationManager != null) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 */
public double getLatitude()
{
    if (location != null)
    {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 */
public double getLongitude()
{
    if (location != null)
    {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 */
public boolean canGetLocation()
{
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 */
public void showSettingsAlert()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    //Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Title");

    //Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("gpsmessage");

    //On Pressing Setting button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    //On pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("cancle", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}

/**
 * Get list of address by latitude and longitude
 *
 * @return null or List<Address>
 */

public List<Address> getGeocoderAddress(Context context) {


    if (location != null) {

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,
                    longitude, 1);
            return addresses;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error : Geocoder", "Impossible to connect to Geocoder",
                    e);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Try to get AddressLine
 *
 * @return null or addressLine
 */
public String getAddressLine(Context context) {
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);

        return addressLine;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Try to get Locality
 *
 * @return null or locality
 */
public String getLocality(Context context) {
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String locality = address.getLocality();

        return locality;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Try to get Postal Code
 *
 * @return null or postalCode
 */
public String getPostalCode(Context context) {
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();

        return postalCode;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Try to get CountryName
 *
 * @return null or postalCode
 */
public String getCountryName(Context context) {
    List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        String countryName = address.getCountryName();

        return countryName;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

And my Splash Activity where i am demanding for postal code and other stuff:
Note ValuetoPass,Coordinates and CordinateLoc are other classes in other activitites for passing the information i have used them

```
package com.example.na462.sunshine;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.URL;

import static android.R.attr.animation;
import static com.example.na462.sunshine.R.id.MainList;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity implements Animation.AnimationListener {
Animation animation,TextAnimation;
Double Latitude;
Double Longitude;
String Country;
ImageView imageView;
ImageView ErrorImage;
TextView AnimationText;
Button ErrorReload;
LinearLayout Layout;
String PostalCode;
Receiver receiver;
boolean Connection;
GPSTracker gpsTracker;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    AnimationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextAnimation);
    ErrorReload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ErrorReload);
     imageView = (ImageView)(SplashActivity.this).findViewById(R.id.Animation);
    Layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Error);
    ErrorImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Nointernet);
    gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(SplashActivity.this);
    gpsTracker.getLocation();
    receiver = new Receiver();
    Connection = receiver.internetconnection(SplashActivity.this);

    if(!Connection || !GPSEnabled.GPS){
        imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ErrorImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AnimationText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }
    else {
        AnimationText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ErrorImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ScrollingActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                finish();
            }
        }, 8000);



        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
        animation.setAnimationListener(this);
        imageView.startAnimation(animation);


        TextAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.blink);
        TextAnimation.setAnimationListener(this);
        AnimationText.startAnimation(TextAnimation);

        new FetchGPS().execute();

    }
}

private class FetchGPS extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Latitude = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
        Longitude = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
        Country = gpsTracker.getCountryName(SplashActivity.this);
        PostalCode = gpsTracker.getPostalCode(SplashActivity.this);
        CordinatesLoc.Latitude = Latitude;
        CordinatesLoc.Longitude = Longitude;
        CordinatesLoc.CLatitude = Latitude;
        CordinatesLoc.CLongitude = Longitude;
        CordinatesLoc.Country = Country;
        Coordinates.Latitude = String.valueOf(Latitude);
        Coordinates.Longitude = String.valueOf(Longitude);
        CordinatesLoc.Postal = PostalCode;
        ValuesToPass.Pincode = PostalCode;
        ValuesToPass.Country = "in";
        return PostalCode;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}

// Its an onclick Method For Retry if there isnt any conncection or GPS Estabished


public boolean ErrorReload(View V){
    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    AnimationText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ErrorImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    gpsTracker.getLocation();
    Connection = receiver.internetconnection(SplashActivity.this);
    if(!Connection || !GPSEnabled.GPS){
        imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ErrorImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return false;
    }
    AnimationText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ErrorImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ScrollingActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            finish();
        }
    }, 8000);


    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
    animation.setAnimationListener(this);
    imageView.startAnimation(animation);




    TextAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.blink);
    TextAnimation.setAnimationListener(this);
    AnimationText.startAnimation(TextAnimation);


  new FetchGPS().execute();
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: There is lots of topics about GPSTracker, just try to find. You can also read this blog http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082062/code-will-only-return-0-0-0-0-gps-coordinate-while-throwing-nullpointerexceptio

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check your manifest.mf file. Maybe you need to add a permission to locate your smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

i think code works fine...sometimes GPS cannot track coordinates in buildings. best solution is to use fused location provider api