# (0,0) latitude and longitude is being displayed on the android device

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The following GPSTracker.java and location.java when run on the android device even after the location is on and the permissions are set is showing (0,0)and even after connecting to the firebase the values are not getting updated to the database(i have done all the firbase database setup) can anyone help me

GPSTracker.java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
private final Context mContext;
boolean isGPSEnabled=false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled=false;
boolean canGetLocation=false;
Location location;
double latitude;
double longitude;

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATES=10;
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES=1000*6*1;
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context){
    this.mContext=context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation(){

    try{
        locationManager=(LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled){

        }else{
            this.canGetLocation=true;
            if(isNetworkEnabled){
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                        (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            return null;
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATES,this);
                if(locationManager!=null){
                    location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    if(location!=null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
                if(isGPSEnabled){
                    if(location==null){
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.
                                GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATES,this);

                        if(locationManager!=null){
                            location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                            if(location!=null){
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return location;
}

public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager!=null){
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

public double getLatitude(){
    if(location!=null){
        latitude=location.getLatitude();
    }
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    if(location!=null){
        longitude=location.getLatitude();
    }
    return longitude;
}

public boolean canGetLocation(){
    return this.canGetLocation;
}
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog =new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is Settings");
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
}
```

location.java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.test.mock.MockPackageManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class location extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    Button btnShowLocation;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION=2;
    String mPermission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

    GPSTracker gps;
    TextView location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        try{
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,mPermission)!= MockPackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{mPermission},REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        btnShowLocation=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gps=new GPSTracker(location.this);
                location=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationText);
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){
                    double latitude=gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude=gps.getLongitude();
                    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    location.setText(latitude+"   "+longitude);
                    myRef=database.getReference("Location");
                    myRef.setValue(latitude+","+longitude);
                }else{
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43082164/115145

Comment: http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/      GPSTracker is broken at the design level and should never be used, it was written without a full understanding of the location subsystem and attempts to over simplify some things.