# My getLocation Method always return null

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am making an app to get user location and display it on google maps but the app always crash since the getLocation method return null value,could any one tell me what is the problem ?

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.getyourlocation">

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and this is my GpsManager.java class which created to get the location on the user

```
package com.example.android.getyourlocation;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;

/**
* Created by Hazem_Khaled on 2017-11-24.
*/

public class GpsManager extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context context;
protected LocationManager mLocationManager;

boolean isGpsEnabled;
boolean isNetworkEnable;
boolean canGetLocation;

Location mLocation;

public GpsManager(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.isGpsEnabled=false;
    this.isNetworkEnable=false;
    this.canGetLocation=false;

}

public Location getLocation(){
    try {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //to find Location via GPS
        String provider=LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        isGpsEnabled=mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider);

        //to find Location via Network
        provider=LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        isNetworkEnable=mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //process to find Location via GPS
            if(isGpsEnabled){
                if(mLocation == null){
                    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,10000,10,this);
                    if (mLocationManager != null)
                        mLocation=mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                }
            }

            //if mLocation still null this means that user location could not be found via GPS then we will use the Network to get user Location
            if(mLocation == null){
                if(isNetworkEnable){
                    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,10000,10,this);
                    if (mLocationManager != null)
                        mLocation=mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Error : ","in getLocation Method");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mLocation;
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

}

and this is my MapsActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.getyourlocation;

import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

private Location mLocation;
private GpsManager mGpsManager;

double latitude;
double longitude;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    mGpsManager = new GpsManager(getApplicationContext());
    mLocation = mGpsManager.getLocation();


    latitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
    longitude = mLocation.getLongitude();

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myLocation).title("I Am Here"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myLocation));
}
```

}

Comment: Another victim of androidhive's so called tutorial

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43082164/115145

Comment: @Selvin thats for sure . Great catch .

Answer (score 0):

With the new API you could try this

**build.gradle**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
```

**GpsManager.java**

```
public class GpsManager extends LocationCallback {

    private FusedLocationProviderClient client;
    private Callback callback;

    public interface Callback {
        void onLocation(Location location);
    }

    public boolean start(Context context, Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
        if (!checkLocationPermission(context)) return false;
        client.requestLocationUpdates(getLocationRequest(), this, null);
        return true;
    }

    public void stop() {
        client.removeLocationUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
            callback.onLocation(location);
        }
    }

    private boolean checkLocationPermission(Context context) {
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        return permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private LocationRequest getLocationRequest() {
        return LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(30_000L)
                .setFastestInterval(20_000L);
    }
}
```

... and attach it like this to your `Activity`...

**MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GpsManager.Callback  {

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private GpsManager mGpsManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mGpsManager = new GpsManager(getApplicationContext(), this);

        // check if user gave permissions, otherwise ask via dialog
        if (!checkPermission()) {
            getLocationPermissions();
            return;
        }

        mGpsManager.start();
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGpsManager.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocation(Location location) {
        // do something with your location
    }

    // CHECK PERMISSIONS PART

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        return isGranted(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) &&
                isGranted(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION));
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void getLocationPermissions() {
        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int code, @Nullable String permissions[], @Nullable int[] results) {
        switch (code) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION:
                if (isPermissionGranted(results)) {
                    getLocationRequest();
                }
        }
    }

    private boolean isPermissionGranted(int[] results) {
        return results != null && results.length > 0 && isGranted(results[0]);
    }

    private boolean isGranted(int permission) {
        return permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
}
```

Now you have to make sure to have all the permissions in your

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to Update Google Play services
2. add to gradle, `classpath 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'`
3. `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` , add this inside allprojects->repositories
4. add `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'` inside dependecies of build.gradle(Modeule.app)